# Signed and unsigned numbers in verilog

Tags: digital-logic, filter, verilog, digital-communications

I understand the concept of fixed point and multiplying signed with unsigned by sign extension the unsigned number with 1 bit of '0' so it will be signed always positive number, But my question

If I want to multiply -186 which is '1101000110' with a fraction 6-bit number of 0.5 which is '100000'

So I want to sign extend the fraction number to be '0100000' so this fraction number will it seen as 0.25 not 0.5 !

In other words how can I write 0.5 in signed always positive number

Comment: uh, what? If you sign-extend 0.5 it stays 0.5, it doesn't become 0.25.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the mistake of "shifting" the number right when adding zeros to the front.

Let me give you the equivalent in decimal.

If we take the number 5 we can add as many zero to the front as we like. Thus 5, 05, 005 etc. are all the same number. If I write that up 'aligned' we would see:

```
    5
   05
  005
```

Most people are more familiar with this notation in fractional format:

```
    5.0
   05.0
  005.0
```

Thus the position of the decimal point stays the same. When you are multiplying you also have to 'align'<sup>**</sup> the numbers:

```
1101000110.000000
          .100000 x
-----------------
```

Now you can add zeros to the front and end up with:

```
1101000110.000000
0000000000.100000 x
-----------------
```

<sup>**</sup>This way of alignment for multiplication is the way I have been taught in my country. I don't know how universal that is.